# DNS, Do A Record wildcards have priority over more-specific CNAMEs?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

We have a wildcard set up to handle all subdomains for "example.com"

A RECORD: *.example.com points to 10.10.10.10

We have a more specific A record to handle a special subdomain (this works fine):

A Record: staging.example.com points 10.10.10.9

The problem we're having is we're migrating staging to a new hosting environment and we've been instructed to use a CNAME:

CNAME: new-staging.example.com points to proxy.heroku.com

We thought this would work. However, new-staging.example.com resolves to the top-level wildcard 10.10.10.10 and doesn't point to proxy.heroku.com.

What am I missing? Is this not possible? Or is this bad practice? Thanks,

Comment: Are you setting this live through an ISP's web interface or are you running BIND or djbdns for example ?

Comment: When you say "resolves to the top-level wildcard", how are you doing this resolution? `dig -t ANY new-staging.example.com` ?

Comment: @Jonathan, we are currently using Slicehost to manage DNS, so it's through a web-interface.

Comment: @nickgrim when running dig -t ANY new-staging.example.com we get:

new-staging.example.com. 82880 IN CNAME proxy.heroku.com.example.com.
proxy.heroku.com.example.com. 86400 IN A 10.10.10.10

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is generally "No" - the more specific record should win, so this should work as you described/expected.  My guess is you have the wildcard A record cached somewhere, and need to wait for that cache to expire.

a quick test with BIND 9.6.2-P2/FreeBSD 8.1:
A zone containing the records:

```
example.net.                IN      A      127.0.0.2
*.test.example.net.         IN      A      127.0.0.1
specific.test.example.net.  IN      CNAME  example.net.
```

Resolves as follows:

```
% dig specific.test.example.net

; <<>> DiG 9.6.2-P2 <<>> specific.test.example.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17222
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;specific.test.example.net. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
specific.test.example.net. 3600 IN  CNAME   example.net.
example.net.               3600 IN  A   127.0.0.2

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.net.        3600    IN  NS  ns1.example.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.example.net.    3600    IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

(Returns the CNAME)
and

```
% dig nonspecific.test.example.net

; <<>> DiG 9.6.2-P2 <<>> nonspecific.test.example.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26980
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nonspecific.test.example.net.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
nonspecific.test.example.net. 3600 IN   A   127.0.0.1

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.net.        3600    IN  NS  ns1.example.net.


;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.example.net.    3600    IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

(Returns the wildcard A record)

Comment: Is this in the DNS standards, or is this implementation-specific?

Comment: @Bigbio2002 I *believe* it's part of the standard - [RFC 4592](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4592) is the relevant place to look - my brain is a bit too soupy from writing documentation all day to stomach reading the RFC though so if I'm wrong please slap me with the relevant section :-)

Comment: Updated IETF url for the DNS RFC, almost a decade later, is https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4592

Answer (score 7):

According to your comment on the question:

> when running dig -t ANY new-staging.example.com we get: new-staging.example.com. 82880 IN CNAME proxy.heroku.com.example.com. proxy.heroku.com.example.com.   86400 IN A  10.10.10.10

...you've misconfigured DNS. You need to set the target of the CNAME to `proxy.heroku.com.` - the final period is important! Without it, your DNS server is assuming you're referring to a host within your `example.com` zone - `proxy.heroku.com.example.com` - and that is being caught by the wildcard-record.

Comment: We've got the CNAME record set to "proxy.heroku.com." When we dig the slicehost name server directly (dig @ns1.slicehost.com) the only answer provided points to the CNAME for proxy.heroku.com. When we dig without specifying it gives us the two answers (the ones I posted above that your answer here reflects). This makes me think that perhaps @voretaq7 may right thinking there's a cache issue? Does that line up with what I'm seeing when digging?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to imply that a DNS-cache upstream of you has cached the incorrect (non-period) version. You'll have to wait for the TTL to expire and/or set up a different name in the meantime (`new-new-staging` ?).

Comment: The missing dot is what tripped me up as well.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post researching how this is done a shared Plesk Linux server. In their example they refer to a combination DNS / vhost.conf solution where you have to add to both the vhost.conf and update the DNS.

Quote:
"It has to be the last in the subdomain list, which is ordered alphabetically, so start its name with "zz."
http://kb.parallels.com/2239

My guess is this differs from 'normal' DNS theory whereby the more specific record would be returned.